# How do I fix the custom errors?

Tags: c#, .net, azure

I keep getting this error when trying to run my system

```
<system.web>
    <customErrors mode="Off"/>
</system.web>
```

```
<system.web>

    <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="mycustompage.html"/>

</system.web>
```

Comment: which error you get?

Comment: whenever i run my system locally it runs, but after I attempt deployment and run it, the above snippets of code show up

Comment: Are you trying to deploy your app to Azure Web Apps? That error refers to that you need to add <customErrors mode="Off"/> setting in your web.config file to get the complete error message.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, enable the details of this specific error message by putting the "customErrors" tag in your "web.config" file like this:

[image]

```
 <configuration>
    <system.web>
        <customErrors mode="Off"/>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Now you will get the exact error in your code and you can fix that specific error.

For security reasons, your code will not be shown in the browser for end user until you have not enabled **CustomError mode="Off"** in web.config file.

Answer (score 0):

For security reasons .NET-Websites shows complete exceptions only, if you call them locally. To see the error message you have to choices:

1. Call the website through a browser on the Server (of course not possible, if you deploy to a Azure WebApp, but e.g. in a VM)
2. Add the first of your snippets (customErrors mode="Off") to your web.config. Then you'll see the complete exception even remotly over the network. My advice would be to set it back to the default setting after you've seen and fixed the error.